# Error with name "Undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used Datepicker | Jquery UI. The code is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'd-m-yy'
            });     
        });
    </script>
```

and I have used http://www.datatables.net/ for search using a keyword

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.dataTables.min.css">
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#enquiry_table').dataTable();     ---->  (I am getting error here)
     } );
   </script>
```

When I use both in a single file I am getting `Undefined is not a function` error. But when I remove one and implement any one of both I am not getting any errors i.e when I use both plugins together I am getting an error, but when used separately I am not getting an error. How to solve this?

Comment: Remove `<script src="<?php echo $this->BaseUrl();?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`. You're loading jQuery twice. You only need it once, no matter how many libraries you are using.

Comment: Can you please more descriptive about error? which line are you getting? line no should be printing on console. And please put full the code where you have used both plugins

Comment: I've edited the question and have showed where I am getting error -@G45

Comment: @Matt- I have removed that line still I am getting the same error

Comment: is plugin file loading?

Comment: ^^^ this. Look at your src for dataTables.min.js. If you use Firebug or similar, can you see if the file is loading or not?